# Wordpress - /page/2 not working but /?paged=2 is

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I have a WordPress site where my front page is showing the latest posts.

If I have my permalinks set as plain showing...

https://example.com/paged?=2

The page loads. However, If I change the permalinks to Post name, giving me...

https://example.com/page/2/

That results in a 404.

.htaccess seems to be set up correctly. The first page has posts and the links are being generated in the pagination controls. Using Post name as the permalink setting my posts are properly linked...

https://example.com/my-wordpress-post

But https://example.com/page/2/ does not work.

Any ideas? I really need to set the permalinks to Post name. Could it be a server issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out. Instead of selecting Post Name, I select the Custom Structure radio button instead and manually added /%postname%/ and then clicked saved.

Then it worked. :)

Comment: Likely, this simply flushed the rewrite rules ... without editing anything, simply saving the Permalink page will flush rewrite rules.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would recommend is to confirm your .htaccess file is set up correctly to process permalinks.  If you create a new page, can you access that page with his human-friendly permalink, for example?  If not, you may need to fix your .htaccess file to handle those rewrites properly.

Otherwise, can you provide more context for this issue?  Is it safe to assume you have your homepage set up with a list of paginated posts?

Comment: I updated my question. It handles all other permalinks I can see so far. Just not the url specified.